# Complete list of paste operation constraints?

Tags: copy-paste, paste

I've programmed for quite a long time - yet I never knew, until today - that folders can't be pasted into themselves.

I found this out in a rather unpleasant way - in my application (we're working on a file browsing app), when I pasted the folder into itself - it caused a segmentation fault (infinite recursion).

```
02-22 04:01:35.186: A/libc(786): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 786 (explorermanager)
```

My question is: are there any other **paste constraints** I **should be aware of** and are also appliable to most platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Win32 you can indeed copy a directory into itself. However if it is not put within a sub-directory it will simply overwrite existing files.

NOTE: For large directories this solution WILL take a little time.

```
// Make sure to link default lib "Shell32.lib"

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>

int main() {

    SHFILEOPSTRUCT hFileS = { 0 };

    hFileS.hwnd = NULL;
    hFileS.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    hFileS.fFlags = FOF_SILENT;

    hFileS.pTo = "C:\\DevkitPro\\TEST\0"; // Put into sub-dir TEST
    hFileS.pFrom = "C:\\DevkitPro\\*\0";

    SHFileOperation(&hFileS);

    return 0;

}
```

Hopefully this helps (if you are using Windows)...

On MSDN:

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647743.aspx

Comment: Paste folders into themselves, not other folders.

Comment: OH, That is very interesting... I never heard of doing that. Well, you could just parse the folder, copy every file individually and paste it wherever (as long as no naming conflicts occur)...

Comment: NOTE: In the example I am copying my DevkitPRO dir into itself (in subdir TEST)! Also DevkitPRO is an amazing toolkit for developing on Nintendo systems!